# iCloud storage is full, how to find each folder size?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, icloud

I'm using a 50GB plan on iCloud and now it seems to be almost full. I received the message saying it is almost full and checking iCloud discovered there is less then 1GB free.

I would like to know which are the biggest files/folders, so I can move them elsewhere. I tried to find folder size in the following way:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:com~apple~CloudDocs me$ du -h -d 1
184M    ./SomeFolder
1.4G    ./AnotherFolder
5.5G    ./Me
4.4M    ./.Trash
 16K    ./Downloads
7.0G    .
```

But, due to the mechanics of iCloud (I think) some files are stored on iCloud only, and so I'm failing to get the full size of everything.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 10):

You can see the file sizes in Finder! If you select iCloud Drive in the sidebar and get info on an item (select item and press **cmd+i**), it will show how much space it takes up in iCloud *and* how much space it takes up on your disk.

To make it easier to find the largest folders, make it show in List view, press **cmd+J** to open the View Options panel and enable "calculate all sizes". This makes it list sizes for folders as well as files, so you can see at a glance which folder contains the most space and even sort by size.

Note, though, that this will only show you the files in iCloud Drive; your space may be used up by other features like email or photos, if you enabled iCloud Photos.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could go to System Preferences > iCloud > Manage, and see which files take the most space.

Comment: This only works with the command J trick that Alex Wally's answer explains below

Comment: This is a wrong answer, no such possibility in Preferences. It only shows total size of iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you mean. The problem is that iCloud drive is not a good representation to understand what you have on iCloud unless you sync everything.

To understand what you have on icloud alltogether it's best to go to icloud.com

From here you can access the diferent folders that are created by the different applications and devices. The problem is that Apple does not provide sorting options or list views making it difficult to use. You either do manual or use icloud for Windows and do all the managing there. Granting you all kinds of additional options for sorting and managing that Apple on Mac or their website doesn't provide.

Comment: iCloud.com does not provide any size information